# upload media file to kurento media server

Tags: file-upload, http-post, media, kurento

I am building an media site using WebRtc and Kurento Media Server with some streaming, recording and filtering features. And now i stuck at the uploading media file to media server feature.

how to upload a media file to kurento media server.

Comment: how did you end up with the question?